# shell command segmentation fault (ICS)

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

On Cyanogenmod 11 (Kit Kat) I was running [this ffmpeg binary](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android) from the command line and it worked great.

I needed to downgrade to Cyanogenmod 9 (Ice Cream Sandwich) and now I get a segmentation fault when running the same ffmpeg binary. Is there something obvious that I should check out?

Comment: Not quite. A segmentation fault occurs, in short, when a software goes writing to a reserved portion of memory. In your case, I can guess that the binary was specifically designed for targets within certain Android versions, and 4.4 is comprised in that range, while ICS is not.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that you found my guess useful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got hold of the developer and learned that the binary isn't compatible with Android ICS or earlier. Simple as that.